# How would I pass an ArrayList of objects to a method?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

If I wanted to create a method in my class `Persons` that adds up all the salaries of all the `Person` objects in my ArrayList called `persons` I created in main, what would I have to do to make that possible? Since I added `person1` in an ArrayList and if I wanted to add another person, how would I pass that to `totalSalary()` so it adds up all the salaries which are properties of the `person1Job`?
My main:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class testPersons {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Persons persons = new Persons();

    Address person1Address = new Address(555, "SumPlus St", "Hayward", "CA", "94544");
    Address person1JobAddress = new Address(1542, "High St", "Santa Cruz", "CA", "94063");
    ArrayList<String> person1Phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    person1Phone.add("555-555-555");
    Job person1Job = new Job("Teacher", 25000.00, person1JobAddress);
    Person person1 = new Person("Edward John", "San Mateo", 'M', person1Address, person1Job, person1Phone);

    persons.addPerson(person1);

  }
}
```

My class Persons:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Persons {


public ArrayList<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<Person>();

public boolean addPerson(Person newPerson) {
    personsList.add(newPerson);
    return true;
}

public double totalSalary() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to pass `personsList` to `totalSalary()`; it's a field, which means you can use it in any (non-static) method of `Persons` automatically.

Comment: Did you try iterating through `personList` in your `totalSalary()`? Also could you also share your `Person` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new Person to the ArrayList by calling your method *addPerson()*.
If you want to compute total salary, just invoke the method *totalSalary()* on your *persons* object which already has list of persons. Your totalSalary method would look something like this.

```
public double totalSalary() {
 double salary = 0;
 for(Person person : this.persons) {
   salary += person.getJob().getSalary();
 }
 return salary;
}
```

If you want to pass list of persons to compute salary, you can do like this:

```
public double totalSalary(List<Person> persons) {
     double salary = 0;
     for(Person person : persons) {
       salary += person.getJob().getSalary(); 
     }
     return salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your Job class, im assuming it has a getSalary function.

```
 public double totalSalary() {
        double total=0;
        for(int i=0;i<personsList.size();i++){
          total+=personlist.get(i).getJob().getSalary();
        }
        return total;
    }
```